# not allowing conversion of specific text in mvc helper extension

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

```
public MvcHtmlString PopupList(List<string> myList)
{
  TagBuilder ulBuilder = new TagBuilder("ul");
  foreach (var item in myList)
  {
        TagBuilder liBuilder = new TagBuilder("li");    
    liBuilder.InnerHtml =item;
    ulBuilder.InnerHtml += liBuilder;
  }
MvcHtmlString.Create(ulBuilder.ToString());
}
```

when i have 'myList' variable with having html tags then i want to not convert to html on output

Comment: solved by converting function return type to `IHtmlString`  with using   `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` for item

Answer (score 0):

Use [HTML.Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> HTML encoding makes sure that text is displayed correctly in the
>   browser and not interpreted by the browser as HTML. For example, if a
>   text string contains a less than sign (<) or greater than sign (>),
>   the browser would interpret these characters as the opening or closing
>   bracket of an HTML tag. When the characters are HTML encoded, they are
>   converted to the strings < and >, which causes the browser to
>   display the less than sign and greater than sign correctly.

Comment: Tried in `PopupList` method? Your method's parameter as `myList` but in foreach you are use `lst`

Comment: i have tried `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` which convert "<br/>" to "&lt;br/&gt;" but on view it shows breakline.